# media queries not responding to the proper screen size

Tags: html, css

I'm using the latest version of Firefox and my media queries are mostly working fine.  The strange thing is that they aren't responding in the correct way to my screen size.  Here is the example:

```
.div{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    text-align:left;
    color:#000000;
    line-height:18px;
    margin-right:15px;
    display:inline;
} 

@media all and (max-width:1366px){.div{
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    text-align:left;
    color:#000000;
    line-height:18px;
    margin-right:15px;
    display:inline;
} }
```

Right now my browser is set to 1600 width, yet it is still using the code within the media query (rather than the default code above).  Why would it be doing this when I set (max-width:1366px)?  I've noticed this in many other cases throughout my css code.  I've worked around it before, but want to make sure there isn't a simple explanation.

Comment: `.div`?? Are you sure about the class name?

Comment: I changed the class name for the example.  It's different in my code.  It's a long name so I figured this would be simpler.

Comment: any JSFiddle you can provide?

Comment: I just took a look at that since I've seen a lot of people use it here.  I'm not sure how to set it up in there, but I can dig deeper into it.

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net - put your code in the right Tab. ( you don´t need a normal HTML Strukture ( header, body... )). If you´re done click on `save` and share the link here :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/C3ZQd/ - I assume you have something like this. However its working in Fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your queries: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X56Np/)

Minor thing, you only need to specify properties you want to change, no need to repeat the same thing twice. The styles within media queries cascade just like all CSS.

To troubleshoot the media queries not displaying:

1. How are you setting your display width?
2. Do you have your browser zoom set to 100%?
3. Have you tried setting the media query to a different width to ensure it definitely fires? I've found a tiered set of media queries with an obvious change in each is useful

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .div {
        background-color:red;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
    .div {
        background-color:green;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
    .div {
        background-color:blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  My zoom is set to 100%.  I set my display width through the screen resolution settings in Windows.  I've changed the width of the div and it is firing because the content on the page changes size on refresh.  So the code within the div that specifies max-width:1366px is firing when I've set my screen resolution to 1600px.  Is Windows screen resolution different from what CSS is looking at?

Comment: Looks like your comment pointed me in the right direction.  In Firefox, I kept resetting zoom to default, which I assumed was 100%.  However, when I test in IE, where I can specify 100% for certain, it works.  Then when I zoomed out twice from the Firefox default, I get the same result as IE.  So Firefox must have a default of 150%, which is why it wasn't working.

Comment: Good to hear it's working now. Note that 'width' in 'max-width' is referring to the pixel distance between the far left and far right side of the *browser*, not the actual window. Devices will apparently use the entire screen size, and they do, but only because phones run browsers in full-screen mode all the time

Answer (score 1):

It worked this way in latest version of firefox.
For a visible change I changed float:left to float:right in @media all and (max-width:1366px)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>media test</title>
<style>
.div{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    text-align:left;
    color:#000000;
    line-height:18px;
    margin-right:15px;
    display:inline;
} 

@media all and (max-width:1366px){.div{
    float:right; //just for a visible change
    width:40%;
    text-align:left;
    color:#000000;
    line-height:18px;
    margin-right:15px;
    display:inline;
} }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras congue, neque a luctus euismod, nisl massa faucibus erat, nec malesuada ante felis eleifend risus. Nullam nec lectus quam. Vestibulum hendrerit erat non tristique interdum. Curabitur pulvinar, risus molestie imperdiet egestas, erat diam mattis lacus, non imperdiet nibh sem id metus. Donec sed est turpis. Proin ultricies pharetra massa eget suscipit. Quisque eget enim placerat, tempor turpis vestibulum, euismod augue. Suspendisse placerat adipiscing porttitor. Nunc tempor vehicula felis at eleifend. Pellentesque vel ornare sem. Sed vitae neque vehicula, malesuada odio sed, dictum elit. Donec enim diam, placerat et ante pulvinar, tempus mattis massa. Fusce tempor dignissim dignissim. Quisque consequat risus id metus porttitor semper. Nunc ut facilisis neque. Vestibulum at ante sem.
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, if you set your screen resolution to 1600 width, is it using the default code or the media query code?  For me, it's using the media query code even though 1600px is wider than the max.